# Perl: file protocol

Tags: perl

Here is my subroutine. But when I click on hyperlink it doesn't do anything while my expectation is to open the file it points.

```
 my $q= new CGI;
  my $tablecontent=[$q->th(['Date', 'Count'])];
  for (sort keys %data) {
    push @$tablecontent,  $q->td([ $_, qq{<a href="file://home/niraj/apache2/log_files/result.$_">$data{$_}} ]) ;
  }
  print $q->table( { border => 1, -width => '20%'},
                   $q->Tr( $tablecontent),
                 );
```

Comment: Not counting the other problems with the code example, do you mean the **click** *in the browser?* If yes, if has nothing with the perl code at all...

Answer (score 3):

Your Perl code is acting as expected. The problem is in your understanding of how the web works.

You present the user with a list of links that look like this:

- file://home/niraj/apache2/log_files/result.xxx

The `file://` protocol indicates a link to a file which is available on the local filesystem (local to the system that the **browser**) is running on. It is very unlikely that those links will work.

You need to create web-accessible links to your files. The easiest approach is to create a symbolic link from the `log_files` directory to a directory underneath the document root of your web server.

Some other things you might consider:

- Indirect object notation (`new CGI`) can lead to some hard to find problems. Far better to use `CGI->new` instead.
- The HTML creation methods in CGI.pm have been [deprecated for some time](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used). Please consider a templating system instead.
- It has been several years since CGI was the best way to write web applications in Perl. Please take a look at some [alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).